# Short story from the 1980s - alien virus erases concept of space travel from modern humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story might have been in *Omni*. Our hero learns that the concept of space travel has been erased from human memory by an alien virus - almost everyone just can't understand the concept even if it's explained.

The main character is apparently only somewhat affected - he can understand the idea when someone else explains it, but doesn't remember satellites or the moon landing.

There's a reference to a UN speech by an south Asian diplomat who bemoaned the deaths in his nation due to bad weather that was not predicted due to lack of satellites - his speech was viewed by the world-at-large as a symptom of a mental breakdown.

The story ends, if I recall correctly, with the situation unresolved - it's clear the aliens will be doing something against humanity in the future, but not clear what people will be able to do in response.